# problem with a LINQ statement using RadComboBox and RadListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik

i have this rad combo box (aka dropdownlist) with items "count" "sum" "max" "min"
which i append to a RadListBox control item so it comes out like this "Count(column1)"
on rcListBoxColumns2.
then i write my code like this and get no result:

```
var ddlFunc = from cp in ddlFunctions.Items.ToList() select cp;
var rcLBC = from p in rcListBoxColumns2.Items.ToList() select p;


havingFilters.DataSource = (from p in rcLBC.ToList()
                                        from x in ddlFunc.ToList()
                                        where p.Value.Contains(x.Value)
                                        select new { Value = p.Value, Text = p.Text }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I can use the debugger and look at ddlFunc and also rcLBC, and I notice rcLBC have values that should "contain" the dropdownlist values, but my result is ALL items being selected. Can't figure out why the contains statement didn't filter it. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you show us sample values for ddlFunctions and rcListBoxColumns2, along with the results you'd expect for these inputs?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I did mention the values of the ddlFunctions: "COUNT" "SUM" "MAX" "MIN". When I have a value in my rcListBoxColumn2 of example: "COUNT(ColumnName)" or "MAX(ColumnName2)", I want to check the string if it contains a value from the ddlFunctions, essentially I'm weeding out the items in rcListBoxColumn2 that have functions attached to them.

Comment: @user354303: Okay, so you're trying to do a `string.Contains`, as opposed to a LINQ `Contains`. I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, apparently my ddlFunctions had a value of "" <- empty string. This caused the string.contains function to return true for any string.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would do it. This is one reason it helps to provide a specific example of your input and expected output. Sorry I couldn't be more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to filter on `Value`, so try this:

```
havingFilters.DataSource = (
    from p in rcLBC
    where (
        from x in ddlFunc
        where p.Value.Contains(x.Value)
        select x).Any()
    select new
    {
        Value = p.Value,
        Text = p.Text
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, I got the same result, getting all values back just like before